# Hadoop MapReduce appcache directory

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm running a MapReduce job on a single-node Hadoop cluster but my disk drive is getting completely filled by attempt_*_spill_*.out files in the {HADOOP_TMP_DIR}/nm-local-dir/usercache/hduser/appcache directory

So my question is: what is stored in this folder and what can I do to limit its size?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During mapreduce execution intermediate data will be spilled to disk, if it is not fit in memory.

But these intermediate data will be deleted automatically as part of cleanup activity at the final stage of mapreduce execution. You cannot limit the size instead more partitions can be specified instead of specifying one partition. `mapreduce.map.sort.spill.percent` can be increased to .90 inorder to minimize the spill percent, but in single node this will create memory issues.

Answer (score -2):

If you have configured Hadoop over linux using VMware or any other tools. Kindly increase ur RAM from the tool settings and try the steps provided by sachinjose. THis may crack ur problem.